# Connect two virtualmachines on different host machines

Tags: networking, virtualbox, nat

In Virtualbox is it possible to connect two VM's on two separate host machines on the same network using NAT?

I currently have two linux boxes (VM's on seperate Host machines) that aren't able to communicate, with that said, both host machines can reach each other.

Comment: Have you tried setting up the interfaces as "Bridged Adapter" instead of "NAT"?

Answer (score 0):

If you've already decided you want to use NAT for their networks, then this isn't really a virtualization question; it's the same situation as getting two physical computers behind NAT routers to communicate over the Internet. You just need to forward the ports that you want (which you can do in VirtualBox's network settings), then connect to the IP of one host from the other host's VM. As @TJJ said, your other option is to used bridged networking instead of NAT, which would let the computers connect with no extra configuration.